# Validate haproxy.cfg

Tags: haproxy

Is there any way to validate the HAProxy `haproxy.cfg` file before restarting the HAProxy service? For example: There might be a small spelling/syntax error in a larger `haproxy.cfg` file. I searched through several forums, but was unable to find anything in relation to validating the `haproxy.cfg` files for syntax errors.

As of now, I use a trial and error basis on a developer machine before I upload the changes to a Production Server.

Comment: Are you using something like `service haproxy reload`? If you are, it should already work like this... it won't restart unless the config is valid, and the old process is unaffected.

Comment: I'm using the `service haproxy restart`. Perhaps I should try the `service haproxy reload` instead. I wanted to know if there was some way of passing/validating the `haproxy.cfg` before restarting it.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The official HaProxy configuration file check was buried in the help sections.

`/usr/local/sbin/haproxy --help`

There are two ways to check the **haproxy.cfg** syntax is to use..

One way is the  `/usr/local/sbin/haproxy -c -V -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`
which validates the file syntax. The **-c** switch in the command represents the Check, while the others denote "Verbose" & "file".

Another way is to `sudo service haproxy configtest`

I hope this helps anyone looking to check the syntax of the *haproxy.cfg* file before restarting the service.

Comment: `sudo service haproxy configtest` is not a recognize option for me with the last haproxy

Comment: `/usr/sbin/haproxy -c -V -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` works for me. Returns "Configuration file is valid"

Comment: How hard is it to install `/usr/local/sbin/haproxy` without then running the service? Say as part of a CI/presubmit process or on a dev machine? -- It *looks* like `sudo service haproxy stop ; sudo systemctl disable haproxy.service` should do the job but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @BCS - you should ask a separate question, but simply running `sudo systemctl disable --now haproxy` would likely be the answer. ;)

Comment: Note that if you have TLS certificates with strict access like you should, you may need to run `sudo haproxy -c -V -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` to check the file or you'll get errors about not being able to read TLS private keys.

Answer (score 47):

We are using this command
`sudo haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -c`